# How to center the modal-title in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to center the h5 of the modal-title in bootstrap.
In a tutorial I saw it's enough to set

```
h5.modal-title{
margin: auto;
}
```

and it looked perfect in the video.(They used Bootstrap4 beta)
but When I do it, it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYu7O.png

```
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does `text-align:center` on the `<div class="modal-header">` not give you the desired effect?

Comment: adding text-align:center; to the modal-header doesn't seem to center anything

Comment: It is a duplicate but all the answers do not center the title to the whole width - only to the closing button

Comment: try `style="margin: 0 auto;"` like `<h5 class="modal-title" style="margin: 0 auto;">title</h5>` it's work fine!